# JPA Entities showing as not enhanced when referenced from another JAR

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I have a Maven Java project with a JAR containing my business logic and JPA persistence entities. Those entities are enhanced by a Maven plug-in at build time. I also have another project which has a dependency on that JAR. i.e.

```
EAR
|->JAR - with entities and persistence.xml
|->WAR - dependent on JAR above
```

When I access the entities from within the JAR everything works fine. However if I try and access the entities from the WAR file I get this error:

```
11:55:07,916 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-4) JBAS014134: 
EJB Invocation failed on component PersonResource for method 
public za.co.shared.PersonDTO za.co.ws.PersonResource.get(java.lang.Long):

javax.ejb.EJBException: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows 
runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at 
build time or at class load time with a javaagent: 

... long list of all my entities

 The type "class za.co.entities.Person" has not been enhanced.
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because the classes are definitely enhanced at build time.

My POM for the JAR project contains:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>za.co.entities.Person</includes>
        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>JPA Enhance</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Can the JPA entities be referenced from a different library?

**Edit**
I've decompiled the WAR file and the JAR that is referenced within it and I can see that the classes are in fact enhanced. So clearly it's not a problem with the way that is working. Could be some sort of configuration problem?

Comment: By the way , in the plugin configuration you are only indicating that Person should be enchanced and not all the other entities :         <includes>za.co.entities.Person</includes>

Comment: We've always done that without problem. All the entities are listed in the `persistence.xml` and as long as one entity is mentioned in the `POM` then the enhancer runs for all. Regardless of if I mention the entity in question in the `POM`, the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I moved all my JPA entities into their own JAR file and referenced that from my EJB modules and from the WAR. i.e.

```
EAR
|->JAR - JPA entities only and pesistence.xml
|->JAR - business logic in EJBs (including EntityManager calls to retrieve data)
|        dependent on JAR above.
|->WAR - dependent on the first JAR only
```

In this way the code in the WAR file can access the JPA entities in the first JAR. However if I add the second JAR as a dependency in the WAR file and try and access the entity manager calls then the original error returns. Also lazy loading on the JPA entities is disabled in the WAR.